# What datatype is considered 'list-like' in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

In the Pandas documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for `Series.isin(values)`, they state:

> values : set or list-like

What is considered list-like? For a Python dictionary `temp_dict`, would `temp_dict.keys()` and `temp_dict.values()` be considered list-like?

Comment: Just try it: `pd.Series(['a']).isin({1: 'a'}.values())`. See also https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_list_like.html

Comment: This is a question about numpy pandas documentation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"List-like" isn't a standard Python term. Googling `pandas list-like` turns up [`pandas.api.types.is_list_like`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_list_like.html), but the documentation for that just says

> Check if the object is list-like.
>
> Objects that are considered list-like are for example Python lists, tuples, sets, NumPy arrays, and Pandas Series.
>
> Strings and datetime objects, however, are not considered list-like.

which isn't really much of a spec. So, as a last resort, we turn to the source code, and after following a lot of imports and aliasing, we eventually find [this function](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.0.3/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx#L1141):

```
cdef bint c_is_list_like(object obj, bint allow_sets) except -1:
    # first, performance short-cuts for the most common cases
    if util.is_array(obj):
        # exclude zero-dimensional numpy arrays, effectively scalars
        return not cnp.PyArray_IsZeroDim(obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        return True
    # then the generic implementation
    return (
        # equiv: `isinstance(obj, abc.Iterable)`
        getattr(obj, "__iter__", None) is not None and not isinstance(obj, type)
        # we do not count strings/unicode/bytes as list-like
        # exclude Generic types that have __iter__
        and not isinstance(obj, (str, bytes, _GenericAlias))
        # exclude zero-dimensional duck-arrays, effectively scalars
        and not (hasattr(obj, "ndim") and obj.ndim == 0)
        # exclude sets if allow_sets is False
        and not (allow_sets is False and isinstance(obj, abc.Set))
    )
```

So Pandas considers an object list-like if it passes this complicated series of checks.

- If an object is a 0-dimensional NumPy array, it's not list-like.
- Otherwise, if it's a list, it's list-like.
- Otherwise, it needs to pass all the following checks to be list-like:

  - It needs to have an `__iter__` attribute that's not `None`.
  - It needs to not be a type.
  - It needs to not be a string, a bytestring, or a "generic alias" (a type used for some `typing` module things).
  - It needs to not have an `ndim` attribute equal to 0.
  - In some cases, Pandas will disallow instances of `collections.abc.Set`, which are sets, frozensets, and certain other set-like objects. (`abc` is `collections.abc` here.)

That means Pandas considers *most* iterable objects to be list-like. Strings, bytestrings, generic aliases, and iterable type objects (like [Enum classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)) are excluded, with that part about excluding iterable type objects probably being a bug - the code is trying to exclude non-iterable type objects whose instances are iterable.

The 0-dimensional array and `ndim==0` checks attempt to exclude objects for which positive-dimensional instances of their type would be iterable, but 0-dimensional instances aren't.

Sets and other `collections.abc.Set` subclasses are sometimes excluded, but `Series.isin` doesn't pass the flag to exclude them.

Answer (score 6):

If you check the Pandas documentation, you find a function that determines whether something [is list like](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_list_like.html). If you do a bunch of searching and searching you eventually end up at a [`pyx` file](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/3c041bc14ba88a6dd67ff3a032afa32379869332/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx#L1219) that defines a C-ish version of the function:

```
cdef bint c_is_list_like(object obj, bint allow_sets) except -1:
    # first, performance short-cuts for the most common cases
    if util.is_array(obj):
        # exclude zero-dimensional numpy arrays, effectively scalars
        return not cnp.PyArray_IsZeroDim(obj)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        return True
    # then the generic implementation
    return (
        # equiv: `isinstance(obj, abc.Iterable)`
        getattr(obj, "__iter__", None) is not None and not isinstance(obj, type)
        # we do not count strings/unicode/bytes as list-like
        # exclude Generic types that have __iter__
        and not isinstance(obj, (str, bytes, _GenericAlias))
        # exclude zero-dimensional duck-arrays, effectively scalars
        and not (hasattr(obj, "ndim") and obj.ndim == 0)
        # exclude sets if allow_sets is False
        and not (allow_sets is False and isinstance(obj, abc.Set))
    )
```

It's a number of conditions. It excluded zero dimensional `numpy` arrays before allowing all lists. What remains must be iterable but not a string, bytes, or generic, not `ndim == 0`, and not a set if that flag is set.